# Fetching data from database and store it into an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, oracle10g

i'm trying to fetch data from oracle database and store it into an array using JavaScript . but the output I'm getting "undefined". how can i fix it?Can anyone help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdata(){
                var con= new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
                var connectionString="Provider= OraOLEDB.Oracle;User id=SYSTEM;Password=xxxx;datasource=ORA";
                con.Open(connectionString);

                var rs=new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Recordset');
                rs.Open("select W_DATE,DATA from xet", con);
                var data=[];
                while(!rs.eof)
                {
                    document.write(data.push[rs(0),rs(1)]);
                    rs.movenext;
                }

                rs.close;
                con.close;
            }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="getdata()">
</body>
</html>
```

here is my data=

w_date              data

1/4/2015 9:27         20.1

1/4/2015 18:52        18.2

2/4/2015 19:00        18.3

2/4/2015 21:25        15.1

I want to get the output as [[1/4/2015 9:27,20],[1/4/2015 18:52,18],....]

Comment: You can't do that.  You need server-side code.

Comment: @Sayka: If you add it to Trusted Sites, or use dangerously low security settings, it might work.  But you should never actually do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to push first.

Then Write..

Try like this..

```
var i = 0;
while(!rs.eof)
{
    data.push([rs(0), rs(1)]);
    document.writeln(data[i++]);
    rs.movenext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are expecting an array of arrays here for your output.

Try something like this:

```
var allRecords = [];
var data = []; 
data.push("1/4/2015 9:27 20.1");
data.push("1/4/2015 18:52 18.2");
data.push("2/4/2015 19:00 18.3");
data.push("2/4/2015 21:25 15.1");

allRecords.push(data);
console.log(allRecords);
```

In your case:

```
var allRecords = [];
var data=[];
while(!rs.eof)
{
    document.write(data.push[rs(0),rs(1)]);
    rs.movenext;
}
allRecords.push(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the output I'm getting "undefined"

[push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) function uses parenthesis, not square brackets.

Use this:

```
data.push([rs(0),rs(1)]);
```

However this will return the index. If you want to output actual data you do something like this:

```
document.write(data[0][0]);
```

Your output format should be something like this:

```
document.write("["+data[0][0] +"," +data[0][1]+"]")
```

or for the sake of simplicity (if you are OK with the separating comma):

```
document.write("["+data[0]+"]")
```

Now all you need to do is play with the indices inside a loop and get your final output.